# Counting substring that begin with character 'A' and ends with character 'X'

Tags: string, substring, counting

PYTHON QN:
Using just one loop, how do I devise an algorithm that counts the number of substrings that begin with character `A` and ends with character `X`? For example, given the input string `CAXAAYXZA` there are four substrings that begin with `A` and ends with `X`, namely: `AX`, `AXAAYX`, `AAYX`, and `AYX`.

For example:

```
>>>count_substring('CAXAAYXZA')
4
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the question ?

Comment: Was probably an accidental edit; requesting reverting to the previous revision.

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't specify a language, im doing c++ish

```
int count_substring(string s)
{
  int inc = 0;
  int substring_count = 0;

  for(int i = 0;i < s.length();i++)
  {
     if(s[i] == 'A') inc++;
     if(s[i] == 'X') substring_count += inc;
  }
  return substring_count;
}
```

and in Python

```
def count_substring(s):
   inc = 0
   substring_count = 0
   for c in s:
      if(c == 'A'): inc = inc + 1
      if(c == 'X'): substring_count = substring_count + inc
   return substring_count
```

Comment: can we have an optimal approach other than brute force

Comment: Can you please tell how to take care of duplicate substrings?

Answer (score 1):

First count number of "A" in the string
Then count "X" in the string

using

```
Public Function CountCharacter(ByVal value As String, ByVal ch As Char) As Integer
  Dim cnt As Integer = 0
  For Each c As Char In value
    If c = ch Then cnt += 1
  Next
  Return cnt
End Function
```

then take each "A" as a start position and "X" as an end position and get the substring. Do this for each "X" and then start with second "A" and run that for "X" count times. Repeat this and you will get all the substrings starting with "A" and ending with "X".

Comment: That does not sound like a 1-loop algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution In python:

```
def count_substring(str):
    length = len(str) + 1
    found = []
    for i in xrange(0, length):
        for j in xrange(i+1, length):
            if str[i] == 'A' and str[j-1] == 'X':
                found.append(str[i:j])
    return found
string = 'CAXAAYXZA'
print count_substring(string)
```

Output:

```
['AX', 'AXAAYX', 'AAYX', 'AYX']
```