# Python counts the number of substrings that begin with a character and ends with another

Tags: python, count, substring

For example, given the input string "CAXAAYXZA", there are four substrings that begin with 'A' and ends with 'X', namely: "AX", "AXAAYX", "AAYX", and "AYX".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting substring that begin with character 'A' and ends with character 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349353/counting-substring-that-begin-with-character-a-and-ends-with-character-x)

Comment: That's a very specific duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "CAXAAYXZA"
a = numpy.array(list(s))
start_indexes= numpy.where(a=='A')[0]
end_indexes= numpy.where(a=='X')[0]
print(sum(1 for i in start_indexes for j in end_indexes if i < j))
```

is **one** way you could do this

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a regex and search for groups at each lengths:

```
s = 'CAXAAYXZA'
n = sum(len(re.findall('(A\w{%i}X)' % i, s)) for i in range(len(s)))
```

After executing, `n`, in this case, will be equal to `4`. Or in its expanded form:

```
n = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    # Increase the total by the groups at i
    n += len(re.findall('(A\w{%i}X)' % i, s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "DO YOUR ASSIGNMENTS BY YOURSELF"
string="CAXAAYXZA"
string_char=list(string)
string_length=len(string_char)
print(string_char)
char_first="A"
char_second="X"
for i in range(0,string_length):
    for b in range(i,string_length):
        if(string_char[i]==char_first and string_char[b]==char_second):
            list=[]
            for z in range(i,b+1):
                list.append(string_char[z])
            print(''.join(list))
```

OUTPUT:

DO YOUR ASSIGNMENTS BY YOURSELF

['C', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'A', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'A']

AX

AXAAYX

AAYX

AYX

Comment: Please upvote this, if you used it, I wasted some of my time on this.